# When defining the behavior of an object, is it better to pass an anonymous object or a callback?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have a class that performs some action on its own and receives the result.

```
// This class cannot be modified.
abstract class BaseWorker {

   fun someWork() {
      // blabla...
      onComplete()
   }

   abstract fun onComplete()
}
```

I know there are two ways to freely override the behavior of onComplete in the above class.

```
// case1

fun main() {
  object : BaseWorker() {
     override fun onComplete() {
       // blabla..
     }
  }.someWork()
}


// case 2

class Worker(val callback:()->Unit): BaseWorker {

    final override fun onComplete() {
        callback()
    }
}

fun main() {
   Worker(callback= { //blabla... }).someWork()
}
```

Either one works fine, but I'm not sure which of these two behaviors should be the way to go in Kotlin.

Can you provide an existing document or answer directly on this?

Comment: This seems entirely up to personal preference without more context on use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mentioned ways are correct and would work fine. So first thing you need to take into account - your team approach. It is better to use same way in all same situations.

Then there are some factors that should be mentioned:

- If responsibility on what should happen is on the class outside the worker (in your case it seems to be the root class with `main` method), using callback is more handy. In this way it's easier to invoke various code on work completion.
- If all the variability should be encapsulated in `BaseWorker` children, it's totally should be as implementation of an abstract method.